# Define json specific field is declared or not

Tags: json, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, if-statement

I have **Asp.Net Mvc4** application. In one Action method I have conditional process that return different *json* result as follows:

```
if(true)
{
     return Json(new { count = cartItm.ProductCount, total = cartItm.TotalAmount });
}
else
{
     return Json(new
            {
                thumb = item.ThumbnailPhoto,
                productName = item.Name,
                itemCount = cartItem.ProductCount,
                itemTotal = cartItem.TotalAmount,
                productTotal = cart.TotalAmount,
                productCount = cart.CartItems.Sum(items=>items.ProductCount)
            });
}
```

In jquery click event I can't define which json is returned. I write if condition as follows but get wrong result.

```
  success: function (data) {
            if (data.thumb != null) {//some operations }
            else{//some operations }
```

Perhaps it is very easy problem, but I am new with *json*. Please help me.

*thanks for reply*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for "undefined" instead

```
   success: function (data) {
                if (typeof data.thumb !== "undefined") {//some operations }
                else{//some operations }
```

Because `item.ThumbnailPhoto` on your server may be null. If this is the case, your check will fail.

Comment: thank you, @Khanh TO. It is work fine. I can accept after 7 min:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 success: function (data) {
          if (data && data.thumb) {//some operations }
          else{//some operations }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be because you don't have `data.thumbs` in your first json, in your Action,

```
if(true)
{
     return Json(new { flag = 1, count = cartItm.ProductCount, total = cartItm.TotalAmount });
}
else
{
     return Json(new
            {
                flag = 2,
                thumb = item.ThumbnailPhoto,
                productName = item.Name,
                itemCount = cartItem.ProductCount,
                itemTotal = cartItem.TotalAmount,
                productTotal = cart.TotalAmount,
                productCount = cart.CartItems.Sum(items=>items.ProductCount)
            });
}
```

in your view :

```
success: function (data) {
            if (data.flag == 1) {//some operations }
            elseif (data.flag == 2) {//some operations }
```

didnt check the code, but this must work.